# Is there a way to create a group header that does not sacrifice space on a detail line in Report Builder?

Tags: reporting, ssrs-tablix

I would like to add a group header rows in a Report Builder report that fires whenever a field value changes without using space on the Details line.

Is there any way to do this in Report Builder? I can do this in Crystal Reports, R&R Report Writer, Access, etc.

The image below is from on-line documentation for Report Builder. In this example there are Date and Order groups. Each group costs whitespace on Detail lines that I could put to productive use.

[image]

I would like to create a report that looks like the image below:

[image]

-Is it possible to reclaim and use the empty space in Detail rows that are occupied by the Date and Order groups Report Builder?

- In the report that I have sketched out above, I am using most of the available space in the Detail rows.
- If I use the report shown in the Microsoft example in the first image, for long orders, I could have pages of empty Date and Order columns.
- Is it possible to use a different report writer (such as Crystal Reports) with SSRS?
- Could we use a .NET application with SSRS instead of Report Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click a cell on the detail row (not a group cell),
***Insert Row*** -->  ***Outside Group - Above***

[image: inserting a group header]

If you run the report you should see that at the top of each group you get a blank row.

Typically, you want the column headers at the top of each group, so cut (Ctrl-X) & paste (Ctrl-V) from the table column headers into this new group header row.

Now you are ready to add a "banner" (merged) row inside the group header (above the column headers row). Right-click on the gray row selector at the left hand side of the table:  ***Insert Row*** -->  ***Inside Group - Above***

Select the cells in the newly inserted row, right-click, and merge them.

Place the grouping information in the merged row.

Delete the column(s) with grouping info from the details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still cannot get around the problem of the column being automatically allocated. Additionally, the Merge is always greyed out for the "Insert Row --> Inside Group - Above".  I have not seen any case where Merge is not greyed out. As soon as I add a group, I lose space on the detail line.

Comment: I think the problem is: I still need a group header to fire when the group changes. If I use a group header it fires but leaves a blank column unit the group header changes. If I use the "Insert Row --> Inside Group - Above" it only fires once - regardless of how many times the group changes. I don't think the capability of Crystal Reports, R&R Report Writer are available in Report Builder.

Comment: Did you complete the last step: Delete the column(s) with grouping info from the details.

Comment: Yes - I did. What I would like to do is add a group header that fires when the group expression changes without having the group expression repeated on the detail line. If I define a group, Report Builder automatically adds the group expression to the detail line. I have not been able to get a simple group header that simply prints when the group expression changes. Removing the redundant column deletes the entire detail row. I am to the point of writing this as a .NET application just to get something that works.

Comment: Deleting the group-value columns should not delete the entire detail row. afaik, the instructions should work.  Make sure you merge only the cells that should remain after you delete the redundant columns.